# ReactJS render included file not working

Tags: reactjs

Using this setup: https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-boilerplate

Problem is that index doesn't render anything from file form.jsx. It just shows "Index File". I changed the loader to "`test: /\.jsx?$/,`" in webpack config. Any clue what's wrong?

**index.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import formA from './form.jsx';

class index extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Index file
        <formA />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default index;
```

**form.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class formA extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        test
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default formA;
```

**Webpack config**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  // or devtool: 'eval' to debug issues with compiled output:
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    // necessary for hot reloading with IE:
    'eventsource-polyfill',
    // listen to code updates emitted by hot middleware:
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    // your code:
    './src/scripts/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loaders: ['babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    }]
  }
};
```

Comment: can you show your webpack config?

Comment: @erichardson30 added webpack config.

Comment: is `src` in the same folder as your webpack config? You have to point it to the location like `../src` or `./src`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should starts component name with an upper-case letter –
replace `<formA />` with `<FormA />`.

It happend because `<formA />` transpiles into `React.createElement('formA')` and `<FormA />` transpiles into `React.createElement(FormA)`.

In first case you create a *tag* with name `formA`. In second case you create a *component* `FormA`.

[More in React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components)

Comment: Thanks, working now! "To render a React Component, just create a local variable that starts with an upper-case letter:"